# How to create a list from a list of objects with lists

Tags: c#, list, filter, lambda

I want to make a filter with lambda/linq or another different solution.

The question I ask myself is: if there is something in the list of X, this list must be included in a single list and be returned.

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> list1 = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
        List<string> list2 = new List<string> { "d", "e", "f" };
        List<string> list3 = new List<string>();

        X x1 = new X
        {
            id = 1,
            Description = "x1",
            Strings = list1
        };

        X x2 = new X
        {
            id = 1,
            Description = "x1",
            Strings = list2
        };

        X x3 = new X
        {
            id = 1,
            Description = "x1",
            Strings = list3
        };


        List<X> Xis = new List<X> { x1, x2, x3 };

        //My current solution
        //from here
        List<string> strings = new List<string>();

        foreach (var item in Xis)
        {
            if (item.Strings.Count() > 0)
            {
                strings.AddRange(item.Strings);
            }
        }
        //until here
    }

    public class X
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<string> Strings { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I made a solution with foreach. I wanted it with an anonymous function, lambda function, or use with a link. But I'm not "seeing it".

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-8.0)

```cs
var strings = Xis.SelectMany(x => x.Strings);
```